# How to access UserId in account controller in asp.net mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to allocate a row of a table to any user after they registered. This table has a column named UserId and some other columns. I want to set UserId of this table the UserId of new registered user and set other values to 0. I want to do this in Register function. But I don't know how to access UserID in Register function of Account controller.
I use default account controller and its functions. The code Of Register function is:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
                Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

                if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that User is your Model, the controller should be something like this

```
class Account:Controller{

[HttpPost]
ActionResult Register(User myModel){

var myUserId = myModel.UserId;

}
}
```

And your view should start with something like this

```
@model User
```

Comment: @ pollirrata Thanks for answer but I use the defaul Registr function in my prject. I added the code above, and in model class there are just UserName, Password, Email and ConfirmPassword.

Comment: Oh ok.. if you want to access the User info from the MembershipProvider you can use HttpContext.User.Identity object

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring the unique identifier generated for a user upon creation as UserId, you can find it as,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Attempt to register the user
        MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
        var user = Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

        if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
        {
            var userId = (Guid) user.ProviderUserKey; //The unique identifier just created

            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```